# Flutter Search if username is exist or not

Tags: database, flutter

Hello I implement a GestureDetector in my app, everytime when someone tap the button which is a search button for usernames, then the function initateSearch is activated. But when someone is typing a username which doesnt exist then it should be running the method _showSettingPanelForNoPlayerFound() does anyone know why this isnt happend. With this code the function _showSettingPanelForNoPlayerFound() is showing every time even I tap a exist user in my textfield.

```
 initiateSearch() async {

    if(Firestore.instance.collection("SerX")
        .where("Username")
        .get() != searchEditingController.text){

      _showSettingPanelForNoPlayerFound();

    }else if(searchEditingController.text.isEmpty){
      _showSettingPanelForNoEnterSomething();
    }else if(searchEditingController.text.isNotEmpty){
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      await databaseMethods.searchByName(searchEditingController.text)
          .then((snapshot){
        searchResultSnapshot = snapshot;
        print("$searchResultSnapshot");
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
          haveUserSearched = true;
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Should use

```
                var abc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("Your Collection Name")
                    .where("Username", isEqualTo: "Whatever")
                    .get();
                if (abc.docs.length == 0)//not found
                else 
                //found and you could continue with it
```

This should be your code

```
initiateSearch() async {
if(searchEditingController.text.isEmpty){
  _showSettingPanelForNoEnterSomething();
}
else{
  var abc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("SerX")
    .where("Username", isEqualTo: searchEditingController.text).get();

if(abc.docs.length==0){
    _showSettingPanelForNoPlayerFound();
}
else
{

  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
  await databaseMethods.searchByName(searchEditingController.text)
      .then((snapshot){
    searchResultSnapshot = snapshot;
    print("$searchResultSnapshot");
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      haveUserSearched = true;
    });
  });
}
}
```

Comment if it doesnt works with the error. Use latest FireStore Version